# Close IMAP Connection using JavaMail & GMail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [ALERT] Too many simultaneous connections. (Failure)
```

Above is the error I run into occasionally with in a bit of test code I run to verify email functionality in a larger project.  And at the bottom in in the screenshot, you can see all the connections that have been created in the last hour.  There is a button on that page to close `all other` browser sessions, but this does not close IMAP connections.

In my project I do attempt to close connections.  I use the method `closeGmailConnection` after every instance of an opened a connection within the larger project.  But it's clear by the image and the error message that some (or all) of the connections are not closing as I expect.

**So my question is this:  what am I missing to ensure all connections are closed by the `CloseGMailConnection` method?**

```
private Properties props = new Properties();
private Session session;
private Store store = null;
private Folder inbox;

public void CloseGMailConnection()
    {
        if (inbox != null) {
            try {
                inbox.close(true);
            } catch (MessagingException e1) {
                log.warn(e1.getMessage());
            } catch (IllegalStateException e2) {
                log.warn(e2.getMessage());
            }
        }

    if (store != null) {
        try {
            store.close();
        } catch (MessagingException e1) {
            log.warn(e1.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalStateException e2) {
            log.warn(e2.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

[image: GMail Connections]

Comment: Are you getting exceptions that cause you to miss calling the close method?  You  might need to use try/finally to make sure the close is called.

Comment: @BillShannon I'm confident that I'm closing the connection every time.

Comment: Then why is Gmail complaining?  Perhaps it's complaining that you've created too many connections in too short a time?  Maybe you need to keep connections open for longer and reuse them?  (Sorry, without knowing more about your application I don't know what else to suggest.)

Comment: @BillShannon the reason I'm opening so many sessions is because I make the connections as part of a ui-test which is run in a CircleCI docker environment so the connections are coming from unique addresses pretty frequently.  Thus my need to close them when I'm done.  For now I've reduced the IMAP an SMTP sessions timeout to 10m hopefully that helps.